# How to translate API response

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, translate

I'm adding product to cart using **{baseUrl}/rest/{store_code}//V1/carts/mine/items**

If requested qty not available in stock then in response you'll get **The requested qty is not available** I want to translate this based on store view ?

Any ideas ? Language pack doesn't work at API level where at theme level it working using language packs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into your issue this morning and I have come up with a work around it. I understand you want to use the Magento translated message in your system that consumes Magento API. I guess your concerns are not to duplicate the existing translation and instead enhance a unified system..

The translation don't seem to be built-in with the API layer in Magento; It may be reasonable to admit this is ok as loading translations has a cost and that would possibly incur api latency issues?

My solution was to add a new API that gives you the translations for the store you use; afterwards, you can cache the result of this translation API call. You can use this API in 2 ways:

**retrieve a single translation:**

```
http://<magento_url/index.php/rest/V1/gettranslation?message=The requested qty is not available&storeId=1
```

**retrieve all the translations:**

```
http://<magento_url/index.php/rest/V1/getalltranslations?storeId=1
```

to be able to consume this additional API, you will have to use the module I have come up with, it is a public repository you can access at:

https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/translationapi/src/master/